# How to return a string with line break from Excel VBA user defined function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to return a string from a VBA function `=Showtext(A1,A2)` like

```
Function Showtext(s1 as string, s2 as string) 

Showtext= s1 & chr(10) & s2

end function
```

however, when calling `=Showtext("Hello","World")` it displays as `Hello World`  in the cell instead of

```
Hello
World
```

I have tried other chars like `chr(13), vbnewline, vbcrlf`, but no luck

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable "Wrap Text" in the cell(s) containing the function ?

Comment: Thank you Tim, that is the key thing I missed. Now it works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Showtext = s1 & vbNewLine & s2`. Note the capital 'N' and capital 'L'.

Your Function definition should also have `As String` after the parameters.

Comment: Thank you Taelsin, it works with "Wrap Text" enabled.